# Make Squid proxy transparent for User-Agent header

Tags: proxy, squid

When I'm using my proxy server (based on Squid3), the proxy server is changing my `User-Agent` request header.

For example, If my browser real agent is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
```

After using my proxy server, the `User-Agent` is empty - changed by the Squid proxy server.

Is this possible that Squid server won't change the `user-agent`? transfer it as-is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found:

```
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use below line in your /etc/squid3/squid.conf

```
sudo vim /etc/squid3/squid.conf

header_access User-Agent allow all
#  TAG: header_access
#       Since squid-3.0 replace with request_header_access or reply_header_access
#       depending on whether you wish to match client requests or server replies.

:wq

sudo service squid3 restart
```